# Validate <param> Using Javascript Parser

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I validate

```
<param name="controller" value="true"></param>

AND

<param name="controller" value="true" />
```

Using same Javascript Parser string. Currently I'm using `/(<param[\s|\S]*?>)[\s|\S]*\/>/i;` which only validates second pattern.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to mark this as a RegEx question?

Comment: Yeah, it's RegEx question! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/<param.*?(?:\/>|><\/param>)/i
```

matches both of them. See example [on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/G848tUiRPe).

Comment: As my first answer, your solution also matches <param name="controller" value="true"/></param>

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
<param[^>.]+(/>[^<]|[^/]></param>)
```

Now it will match only the first two of the four below

```
<param name="controller" value="true"></param>

AND

<param name="controller" value="true" />

AND 

<param name="controller" value="true"/></param>

AND 

<param name="controller" value="true">
```

Comment: This will also match `<param name="controller" value="true">` and `<param name="controller" value="true"/></param>`